# Как скачать видео по ссылке из VK клипы

Tags: python

Всем привет кто ни будь знает как скачивать видео из vk клипы через python а то я пытался скачать через requests он скачивает в формате m3u8 и не открывается если через браузер скачивать в ручную такая же проблема .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете почитать статью вот по этой ссылке: https://codeby.net/threads/zagruzhaem-video-iz-vk-s-pomoschju-python.80481/
Приводить ее здесь полностью не буду. Код достаточно большой.